# Sendgrid emails getting deferred

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid, deferred, mail-server

All the emails which I sent via SendGrid is getting deferred. On the SendGrid Activity dashboard it shows the message. "554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means."

It used to work 3 months ago. For the past 3 months, there were only very few email being sent out. Now All the emails sent are getting deferred.

Please let me know a fix for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the exact same problem, which started occuring recently.

Comment: I think the issue is related to the IP reputation. I have sent a bunch of emails to warm up the IP. now I am receiving some of them after a certain delay.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I'm using shared hosting of SendGrid, so the server is being used by others as well. Go to the activity overview, and click the info icon. You will see more information, in my case it's like:

```
...Client host [149.72.39.137] blocked using Spamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/149.72.39.137...
```

If you click the link, you can see the reason:

[image]

So here it's obvious that some phising was going on, therefore, mails are delayed and/or blocked.

I guess to solve this, we should upgrade to have a dedicated server...

Comment: HI, @L-Four in my case emails are deliveres after a considerable delay like an hour or two. The IP is not blocked. If blocked none would have been delivered.

Comment: That was also the case for me. Some were delayed and delivered after a day, some were blocked.